# How can i parse Salesforce SOQL query using the TSQLStatementReader.ParseStatements?

Tags: .net, salesforce, soql

How can i parse SOQL query using the TSQLStatementReader.ParseStatements ?

I have a SOQL query :

```
var query =  select id, Order.Id, Order.Contract.Id, Order.Contract.Account.Id, 
Order.Contract.Account.Owner.Id from OrderItem
```

and I am trying to parse this into columns by using the following:

```
var statement = TSQLStatementReader.ParseStatements(query.Replace("\n", " ").Replace("\r", " "));
```

But if i debug there is nothing in the From property of the object.

How can i do the parsing or is there a SOQLParser class  ?

Comment: SOQL is not SQL, you will not be able to parse it with a SQL parser.

Comment: It works with the following , SELECT Account.Owner.Name FROM Account WHERE Account.Id IN ('123456') ? Also is there a parser for SOQL  I can use ?

Comment: Because the above query has the reserved word Order, it seems to be parsing everything after the Order. as the OrderBy filed in the object. I have tried wrapping the Order in [] but it get "Unknown error parsing query" , thats in Salesforce Developer Console. Any suggestions on how i can do the query ?